# ASP.NET Role based access

Tags: asp.net, membership, roles

I have the following site structure:

[image]

What I'd expect this to do was to deny anyone who isn't a logged-in user with the `RegisteredUser` role, except on `Reset.aspx` and `Validation.aspx`, where it would allow anyone (logged-in or not) to access, but this isn't the case right now.

Everyone who isn't a `RegisteredUser` isn't able to access these two pages, what am I doing wrong?

**Update** Even this won't work:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>
  <location path="Reset.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>

  <location path="Validation.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

It doesn't make any sense, isn't this supposed to be the system default?

Comment: Have you tried to check rules using ASP.NET Configuration? Open it with small icon in the right corner of the Solution Explorer (or Project\Website->ASP.NET Configuration).

In ASP.NET Configuration use Security -> Access Rules -> Manage Access Rules for the appropriate folder.

Comment: you should specify the path without the ~/

Comment: @coder net: In the original question it was mentioned: "I've placed no restrictive rules up until WebForms\Account, where I have the following configuration in web.config:[...]". In case he uses the web.config placed into the folder (not the main one), he does not need to specify path explicitly, only file names.

Comment: ok, i didn't notice the sub folder web.config. Then you could be right. There seems to be plenty of web.config files in this app. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to map paths, only file names:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>
  <location path="Reset.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
        <deny />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>

  <location path="Validation.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>

  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow roles="RegisteredUser" />
      <deny users="*" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thank you for accepting but how did you solve your issue? You described a strange behavior in your question update. Or was it just a local bug?